# How can i generate a imagick non-linear gradient?

Tags: php, gradient, imagick

i generated a linear gradient with this php code:

```
$image = new Imagick($picture);

$image->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG); 
$image->setImageCompressionQuality(80);     

$image->cropThumbnailImage ( 1920, 1080);
$image->setImageFormat('jpg'); 

$gradient = new Imagick();
$gradient->newPseudoImage(1920, 1080, "gradient:green-transparent");    
$image->compositeImage($gradient, imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0);
```

But the fade to transparent must be deeper. 75% green in the picture an 25% transparent.

Greetings!

Comment: JP(E)G doesn't support transparency

Comment: A gradient overlay is on the picture. thats because the green to transparent gradient